# Open a buffer on a new Tab on Vim

Tags: vim, tabs, buffer, viml, autocommand

I'm creating a Vim plugin that I need intercept when a new buffer is loaded.

The basic idea consists in when I open a new buffer this new buffer must be screened on another tab, and the previous tab must keep the previous buffer loaded.

Eg.: I have a buffer with the `foo.txt`, when I try to open `bar.txt` with `:e bar.txt` It will open in a new tab and the previous tab must stay with the `foo.txt`. **I know that `:tabe bar.txt` does the job**, but to my plugin I need the "`tabe` behavior" even when it's not used to open a file.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this with Vimscript?

*The reason behind this: [https://github.com/vim-ctrlspace/vim-ctrlspace/issues/177](https://github.com/vim-ctrlspace/vim-ctrlspace/issues/177_)*.

Comment: You have given only `tabnew`, not any file name with it. How do you expect it to work?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The previous snippet had `exe "e"file`, of course, I could do a `tabe <file>` but the idea isn't only open a new tab with the file, but open the file in a new tab keeping the previous tab's buffer. I removed the odd snippet in favor an example to make more clear my question.

Comment: So you want to override `:e`? Fine, use [cmdalias.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=746). Personally I think you should just use `:tabe` and forget messing with `:e`. What about other commands `:split`? `:enew`? `:find`? Would you override `gf` to open a tab as well? I feel like doing this would be changing a great deal of Vim to match your choice of plugin(s) and/or a some workflow (possibly a mythical workflow).

Comment: I not exactly want override commands, I want to intercept the buffer opening to redirect it to other tab for my plugin. I made a PoC of my plugin applying very rudimentary commands to do this. This gif https://raw.githubusercontent.com/samuelsimoes/vim-drawer/master/fx/demo.gif shows the idea and this is the way that I accomplished this https://github.com/samuelsimoes/vim-drawer/blob/master/plugin/vim-drawer.vim#L120-L129

Answer (score 2):

You are making things more complicated than needed.

```
augroup tab
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufReadPost * tabedit %
augroup END
```

Comment: This does part of the job, but I need the previous tab keeping the previous buffer.

Comment: Complementing: let say that you are on `foo.txt` buffer, when you try to open `bar.txt` a new tab will open with `bar.txt` and the previous tab will stay with `foo.txt`.

Comment: Well, you are describing the default behavior of `:tabedit` so I'm really confused about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Let's say that you type the command `:e bar.txt`, I want in this situation the aforementioned behavior, an interception when a buffer is created and where it will be placed. This looks weird, but I need this to my plugin idea.

Comment: Trying to explain better I want the `tabe` behavior even when it's no used, like `:e bar.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead * nested
  \ if &buftype != "help" |
  \   tab sball |
  \ endif
```